# How to delay SnackBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, snackbar

How do I display a snackbar after a delay in Flutter? I tried

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 5000), () { ... }
```

but it doesn't delay it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have to do this after your future execution ends. You do this with `then` future method.

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((_) {
         // this code is executed after the future ends.
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar( SnackBar(content: Text("SNACKBAR") ) );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you very much